# General condition that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are the same

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, riemann-sum

I'd like to know that when Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral are the same in general. I know that a bounded Riemann integrable function on a closed interval is Lebesgue integrable and two integrals are the same.

However, I want to know as general as possible condition for two integrals to be the same. For example, in terms of improper integrals, unbounded functions and $\mathbb R^n$ space.

Any answer would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Although this doesn't fully satisfy all your requests, I think it will be useful to state a theorem which appears in some similar form in Folland's Real Analysis (I believe 2.28, though I might be wrong):

**Theorem:** Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is bounded. Then:

1)  If $f$ if Riemann integrable, then $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ equals the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[a,b]} f \, d\mu$ (where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure).

2) Further $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities of $f$ is a $\mu$-null set.

**End Theorem**

Let me make another point about a difference in Riemann and Lebesgue integration from a geometric standpoint. If you notice, the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[a,b]} f \, d\mu$ has no "orientation" with respect to the interval $[a,b]$, whereas the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ we interpret as "the integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$" and, in fact, we have $\int_a^b = - \int_b^a$ for Riemann integrals. To further investigate this point, I'd suggest looking into differential geometry; in this context $dx$ would play the role of the "Riemann volume form" on $\Bbb{R}$ which depends on this orientation, whereas $d\mu$ is an honest measure and doesn't require orientation.

Comment: you mean that this "∫_a^b = - ∫_b^a" kind of property cannot be considered in Lebesgue integral right?

Comment: @user156043 Basically, yes. The "limits of integration" for the Lebesgue integral $\int_E f \,d\mu$ is defined for measurable sets $E$. So to integrate $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$, we consider $[a,b]$ as a measurable set (which doesn't have an "orientation").

Answer (score 12):

The Riemann integrable functions are a subset of  the upper functions $\mathscr L^+(I)$, those functions which are a increasing limit a.e. on $I$ of a sequence of step functions, hence usually a proper subset of the Lebesgue integrable functions $\mathscr L(I)=\mathscr L^+(I)-\mathscr L^+(I)$. That is, whenever $f$ is Riemann integrable over $I$ it is also Lebesgue integrable, and the integrals coincide, but there are functions which are Lebesgue integrable but not Riemann integrable.

You must be careful, however, since *the* Riemann integral is *only* defined for **blocks** in $\Bbb R^n$; i.e. those bounded compact subsets that are products of intervals $[a,b]$, and we may stretch the definition up to Jordan measurable sets, however one can define the Lebesgue integral of a function over any Lebesgue measurable subset of your space. Again, a Jordan measurable set is Lebesgue measurable, but there are Lebesgue measurable sets that are not Jordan measurable.

As a counterpart, the positive improperly Riemann integrable functions *are* Lebesgue integrable, but there are improperly Riemann integrable functions that are not Lebesgue integrable. The usual (counter)example is $x\mapsto x^{-1}\sin x$ over $I=\Bbb R$.

Comment: I want to check that my understanding is right. In the first part, "I" denotes a closed and bounded interval right? Then, you mean that any Riemann integrable function on a closed and bounded interval is Lebesgue integrable right? Also, in the second part, you mean that any Riemann integrable function on a Jordan measurable set is Lebesgue integrable and two integrals are the same right? Finally, any positive improperly Riemann integrable function on R^n is Lebesgues integrable right?

Comment: @user156043 Right.

Comment: I don't think that the Riemann integral is defined only for blocks.

Comment: @Laters You could extend the definition to Jordan measurable subsets.

Answer (score 6):

Your statement about "a bounded Riemann integrable function" is correct, but you don't need the "bounded" part: an unbounded function can't be Riemann integrable.
It can have an improper Riemann integral, but that's a different matter.

Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability: A function on a bounded interval $I$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is

1. bounded, and
2. continuous almost everywhere (i.e. except on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$).

Comment: Oh i didn't know that one. thank you!