# Approximation Lebesgue integral

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I've got a continuous function on a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to approximate it's Lebesgue Integral by a sum.

I would consider a disjoint partition $(A_{i})_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $A$ and claim that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\geq N$
$$ \left|\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(v_{i}) \lambda(A_{i}) - \int_{A} \phi(v) \: d\lambda\right|<\epsilon $$
holds where $\phi(v_{i})$ is some value of $\phi$ on $A_{i}$.

Is this possibe?

Comment: Is $A$ a compact set? This would greatly simplify things since as a consequence $\phi$ would be uniformly continuous. Otherwise you can just go back to the definition of the Lebesgue integral, which would immediately gives you the result

Comment: What kind of set is $A$?  Presumably it should at least be a measurable set, which you may be hinting at with the notation $\lambda(A_i)$.  Is that the measure of the various "parts" $A_i$ that decompose $A$?

Comment: just use the definition of the Lebesgue integral to approximate it by a sum

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Yes, $A$ should be the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is compact. So the Riemann and Lebesque integrals would coincide here and that's why I can approximate it by this Riemann sum? Do you mean that with 'simplify'?

Comment: @Lae what you wrote is not necessarily a Riemann sum, it depends on what kind of $A_i$ had you chosen

Comment: Note that the $(n-1)$-sphere has measure zero in $\mathbb R^n$.  So the notation $\lambda(A_i)$ really needs clarification/definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of computing the integral is exactly the definition of the Riemann integral. It is also known that the Lebesgue integral coincides with the Riemann integral when both are defined, so this is correct.

*That answer was indeed terse, thanks @hardmath for bringing it up!*

**Edit**

Your method of evaluating the integral incorporates the definition of the [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) which is founded on partitions of the set over which the integral is being evaluated. It is also known that the [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) coincides with the Riemann integral when both integrals are defined, so I think this approach is possible (with some caveats).

For instance in $\mathbb{R}$, we approximate the Riemann integral of $f(x)$ over some interval $(a, b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as follows. First, we define a partition of $(a, b)$ into $k$ sub-intervals of equal length. Then, we choose arbitrary points $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\dots$, $x_{k}$ from each of these sub-intervals. Then, we take the images of these points under $f$ to get $f(x_{1})$, $f(x_{2})$, $\dots$, $f(x_{k})$.

Each sub-interval has length $(b - a)/k$. From here, we approximate the integral by summing the areas of the rectangles formed over these sub-intervals of heights $f(x_{1})$, $f(x_{2})$, $\dots$, $f(x_{n})$ to get

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} f(x_{i}) \cdot \frac{b - a}{k}$$

This construction is very similar to the finite sum in OP's attempt; each sub-interval has Lebesgue measure $(b - a)/k$. Taking $n \to \infty$, we have the Riemann integral of $f(x)$ over $(a, b)$ so it is not surprising that the Riemann integral will coincide with the Lebesgue integral.

*Without loss of generality, for intuition purposes, we assumed that $f$ is positive over the interval $(a, b)$. The signed integrals can be built on top of this naive definition.*

In this multi-variable setting, the Riemann integral is generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by using the same method over partitions into *boxes* of higher dimensions.

For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we partition the volume under surfaces into cuboids. In rigorous terms, these *boxes* of higher dimension are Cartesian products of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Also, the Lebesgue integral of each of these cuboids coincide with the volume classically defined as *length $\times$ width $\times$ height*.

In this case, for some surface $f(x, y)$, our sum would look like

$$\sum_{i \in I} f(P_{i}) \cdot V(A_{i})$$

for some index set $I$ that enumerates the squares $A_{i}$ that form the partition. Here, the $P_{i}$'s are the points chosen from each square $A_{i}$.

In the OP's attempt, we are using the Lebesgue integral, so our $A_{i}$'s do not necessarily need to be *boxes* in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In the Riemann integral, we are only limited to *boxes* (or countable unions of these *boxes* to form irregular shapes, see [Peano-Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure)). But this limitation does not apply to the Lebesgue integral.

Hence, it is indeed possible, with the pre-requisite that the Lebesgue measure is defined on each of these $A_{i}$'s that make up the partition of the region of integration. Hence, the only caveat is that we require $A_{i}$'s to be Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Done. How about now? :)

Comment: Thanks, it certainly is food for thought.  I'm adding a link to this previous Question [General condition that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829927/general-condition-that-riemann-and-lebesgue-integrals-are-the-same), whose answers also touch on the limitations of the Riemann integral definition in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer :)