# Can we prove that $\displaystyle 12 \int_{0}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx\le\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^4)(f''(x)) ^2dx$ if $f''$ is only Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $f:[0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a two times differentiable function such that $f''$ is Riemann integrable, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. Is it true under these assumptions that $$12 \int_{0}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx\le\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^4)(f''(x)) ^2dx?$$

The source of my problem is [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u354682h1671265p22909402), where I also proved this inequality if $f$ is a $C^2$ class function, i.e. if we know that $f''$ is not only Riemann integrable, but actually continuous. For the sake of completeness, I will add my short proof here.

By Taylor's Theorem with Integral Remainder we know that $$f(x)=\int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)dt$$
for any $x\in [0,1]$.

Thus, $$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x (x-t)f''(t) dt\right)^2 dx \stackrel{\text{C-S}}{\le}\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{3}\left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right)dx=\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1(1-x^4)(f''(x))^2dx$$ and we are done.

The OP from AoPS required $f''$ to be only Riemann integrable and I wonder if this inequality still holds in that case or if he actually intended $f''$ to be continuous.

So far I've only come up with the idea that maybe I can somehow approximate a two times differentiable function with a Riemann integrable second derivative by a sequence of $C^2$ class functions. I don't know if this is possible (I haven't taken an advanced course in real analysis yet, so please bear with me if there is some well known density argument that I am not aware of), but this is all I could come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Riemann integrability of $f''$ is sufficient to ensure that Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder holds. Using integration by parts, you have
$$
\int_0^x (x-t)f''(t) \, dt = \left[ (x-t)f'(t) \right]_{t=0}^{t=x} + \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt =- x f'(0) + f(x) - f(0)
$$
or
$$
 f(x) = f(0)  + xf(0) + \int_0^x (x-t)f''(t) \, dt \, .
$$

More generally, the [integral form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)
$$
 R_{k}(x)=\int _{a}^{x}{\frac {f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}}(x-t)^{k}\,dt.
$$
is valid if $f^{(k)}$ is absolutely continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$.

In order to show that
$$ \tag{*}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{3}\left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right)dx=\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1(1-x^4)(f''(x))^2dx
$$
we can take a short detour via the Lebesgue integral. A Riemann integrable function on a compact interval is continuous almost everywhere, it is also Lebesgue integrable, and the Riemann integral coincides with the Lebesgue integral (see for example [General condition that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829927/general-condition-that-riemann-and-lebesgue-integrals-are-the-same/829957#829957)).

Therefore,
$$
 g(x) = \frac{x^4-1}{12} \int_0^x f''(t)^2 \,dt
$$
is differentiable almost everywhere on $[0, 1]$, with
$$
g'(x) = \frac{x^3}3 \int_0^x f''(t)^2 \,dt - \frac{1-x^4}{12} f''(x)^2 \, .
$$
The right-hand side is Riemann- (and therefore Lebesgue-)integrable, so that the [fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integral calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) can be applied, and it follows that
$$
0 = g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g'(x) \, dx \\
= \int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{3}\left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right)dx -\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1(1-x^4)(f''(x))^2dx \, .
$$
Finally, all integrals on the right exist as Riemann integrals, so that $(*)$ holds for the Riemann integral as well.

Comment: Yes, I know that Taylor's Theorem works even if $f''$ is only Riemann integrable. The problem is here: $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{3}\left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right)dx=\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1(1-x^4)(f''(x))^2dx$. I use integration by parts for this equality and if $f''$ is only Riemann integrable then I cannot say that $\displaystyle \left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right)'=(f''(x))^2$ (well, I actually only need $(f'')^2$ to be continuous, but whatever).

Comment: @Alexdanut: The identity $\Big(\int^x_0 (f'')^2\Big)'=(f'')^2$ occurs almost everywhere (the exceptional points are points of discontinuity which form a set of measure zero by the assumption of $f''$)

Comment: @Alexdanut: I have updated the answer.

Comment: @MartinR thank you, so I think that what you are saying is that if I have two functions $u, v$ defined on $[0, 1]$ such that $u$ is differentiable and its derivative is Riemann integrable and $v$ is differentiable almost everywhere and its derivative is Riemann integrable, then I may still apply integration by parts, i.e. $\displaystyle \int_0^1 u'v=uv\bigg |_0^1 -\int_0^1 uv'$, right? Can you explain to me why this works, please? I don't know too much about the Lebesgue integral, but in this context is the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 uv'$ the usual Riemann integral?

Comment: @Alexdanut: If $f$ in Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ and $\alpha$ has derivative which is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$, the the Riemann Sieltjes integral $\int^b_a f(x)\,d\alpha(x)$ exists and $\int^b_a f(x)\,d\alpha(x)=\int^b_a f(x)\alpha'(x)\,dx$ (Theorem 7.35 in Apostol's Math. Analysis). The rest is integration by parts for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals (Theorem 7.6, op.cit)

Comment: @Alexdanut: I was thinking in terms of the Lebesgue integral: $g(x) = \frac{x^4-1}{12} \int_0^x f''(t)^2 \,dt$ is differentiable almost everywhere and the derivative is Riemann (and therefore Lebesgue) integrable, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions. It follows that $0 = g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g'(x) dx$, which is the desired formula.  What Oliver said might be an easier way to get the result.

Comment: @Alexdanut: I have added more details. (Again, using the Riemann-Stieltjes integral as suggested by Oliver *may* be a simpler approach.)

Comment: @MartinR thank you very much, now it all makes sense even for someone like me who is  not so familiar with the Lebesgue integral!

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you, I will certainly look into your approach using the Riemann-Stieltjes integral too, even though I have had little to none exposure to this type of integrals.

Comment: It is very similar to The Riemann integral (where you use $\alpha(x)=x$) The theory works well for $\alpha$'s of bounded variation, which in essence means that $\alpha$ is the difference of two monotone nondecreasing functions. In your problem you have $\alpha(x)=f'(x)$ Since $f''$ is Riemann integrable, $f'$ will be of finite variation (over $[a,b]$) In fact, it will be absolutely continuous too.

Answer (score 3):

You can also see that
$$
\int_0^1 {x^3\over 3}\left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right) dx={1\over 12}\int_0^1 (1-t^4)(f''(t))^2 dt
$$
by Fubini's theorem (interchange of the order of integration):
$$
\eqalign{
\int_0^1 {x^3\over 3}\left(\int_0^x (f''(t))^2 dt\right) dx
&= \int_0^1 \left(\int_t^1 {x^3\over 3} dx\right)(f''(t))^2 dt\cr
&=\int_0^1 {1-t^4\over 12}(f''(t))^2 dt.\cr
}
$$
For justification of the application of Fubini you can use the observation of Martin R that $f''$ is Lebesgue measurable and bounded, being Riemann integrable by hypothesis.