# Calculating the integral in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

I'm very new to measure theory, so I don't really understand how to do this:
$\int_Axe^yd\lambda^2$ for A:=$\left\{(x,y)\in R : 0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le \frac1 2 x^2\right\}$

Do I calculate it using regular integral rules? I'm sorry if this sounds like a I don't know anything question, but I am truly lost and I hope that someone can still help out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\lambda^2$ is supposed to be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$, you can simply treat this integral as a Riemann integral, since $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot e^y$ is continuous and therefore Riemann integrable. In this case, the Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral are equal, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829927/general-condition-that-riemann-and-lebesgue-integrals-are-the-same?rq=1).

Now, the Riemann integral can be written as a double integral of the form $$\int_
*^*\int_*^*xe^y dxdy$$ You'll just have to figure out the integration boundaries $(*)$.

Comment: Would it be correct that the first integral we have [0,1] and the second has [0, 1/2] boundrie?

Comment: @ugjumb Not quite. Note that $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and $y$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}x^2$, so at least one of the integration boundaries needs to have an "$x$" in it. Also, try integrating w.r.t. to $y$ first, then w.r.t. $x$, meanin $\int\int xe^y dydx$

Comment: Really? because if we take into account that x can be max 1, so won't that mean that y can only go to 1/2 oor does that train of thought make no sense?

Comment: Doing the dy first I got xe-e, then without boundries dx $e(\frac{x^2} 2 - x)$

Comment: $y$ can go at most to $1/2$, but that does not mean that $y$ $\textbf{ does }$ go up to $1/2$. It only goes to $1/2x^2$ for fixed $x$.

Comment: So it would be fine to put x2\2 as boundry?

Comment: Yes, assuming you mean $x^2/2$.

Comment: I GOT IT! THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theorem that you might find handy:

> Let $f \colon \varOmega \to \mathbb R$ be measurable and $f \geq 0$ almost everywhere. Then
> \begin{equation}
> \int f \, d\lambda = \int_0^{\infty} \lambda\left(\{f \geq t\}\right) \, dt
> \end{equation}